# Creating a bone colored feather dye

Tags: gear, archery, diy

I've white [turkey feathers](http://gatewayfeathers.shptron.com/p/4-r-w-parabolic-flo-white?pp=8).

[image: Feather]

I want to dye them like my nocks:

[image: X-Nock bone]

As you can see, they're "bone" colored (a slightly dirty white). Am I able to make my white feathers a little bit more "creamy"?

---

Edit:

Feather image for bad displays (;P):

[image: Contrast]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feathers take dye well.  Some references suggest that kool-aid can be used. You can use an off the shelf fabric dye. If you want to go natural you could use turkey droppings, and thin to get a consistency that gives the desired color.

Regardless of which type of dye you use it will take trial and error to get the correct mix to give the desired color.  You need not test a whole, feather cut it in to sections and possibly get 5 or 10 trials out of one flight feather.

1. Mix the dye
2. Submerge the feather
3. Rinse the feather
4. Let it dry.